# Solving system $dx = \frac{dy}{2xz} = -\frac {dz}{2xy}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

How to solve the system 
$$dx = \frac{dy}{2xz} = -\frac {dz}{2xy}?$$
How in general such systems are solved? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually these equations arise from the method of characteristics. Some examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

Answer (score 1):

What you call "to solve the system" is not clear but anyway, the solutions of this system can be parametrized as $$x^2=a\pm t,\qquad y=b\cos t,\qquad z=b\sin t,$$ for some $(a,b)$ with $b\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

let us solve $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{4xyz}, \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{2y}, \frac{dz}{dt} = -\frac{1}{2z}.$$  a solution is $$y = \sqrt{t+B}, z = \sqrt{C - t}$$ and $x$ satisfies the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{4x\sqrt{(t+B)(C-t)} }$$ whici\h has a solution 
$$x = \sqrt{A + \int_0^t\frac{ds}{\sqrt{(s+B)(C-s)}}},\  y = \sqrt{t+B},\  z = \sqrt{C-t} $$ where $A, B, C$ are constants to be determined from initial condition.

Comment: downvoter, it would be nice if you leave for your actions. it will help improve the answer. anyway i did find an error and i have fixed that one.